# How to save and use Variables in Spark Streaming?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have **three businesses** called **a,b,c**, they are will be processed in one spark streaming Application.

All businesses depend on `b1` and `b2`, and I need change value of `b1` and `b2` once when finished all businesses in one batch. that is to say, I must change value of `b1` and `b2` before last one bussiness being finished. Maybe last one finished bessiness  is **a** or **b** or **c**. How to do it?

```
object Variables extends Serializable{
    var b1 = true
    var b2 = false
}


object test{
    def main(args: Array[String]){

        val sc = new SparkContext
        val sec = 3

        val ssc = new StreamingContext(sc, Seconds(sec))
        val input = ssc.socketTextStream("192.168.41.55", 12345)

        // a business
        input.transform(/*I need use b1,b2 in here*/).saveAsTextFiles("")

        // b business
        input.transform(/*I need use b1,b2 in here*/).saveAsTextFiles("")

        // c business
        input.transform(/*I need use b1,b2 in here*/).saveAsTextFiles("")

        ssc.start()
        ssc.awaitTermination()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need variables to be shared between the nodes you need to use Spark [variable broadcasting](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#shared-variables) If you are using checkpoints in your spark steaming job you need to lazily initialize these variable [see example here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#accumulators-and-broadcast-variables)